# what compareTo() method compares in java

Tags: java

when we compare strings in java using compareTo() method,what it actually compares, either it compares the length of string or what does it compares?

Comment: Why won't you have a look at the [API (link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two variants of this method. First method compares this String to another Object and second method compares two strings lexicographically.

Syntax:
Here is the syntax of this method:

```
int compareTo(Object o)

or

int compareTo(String anotherString)
```

Parameters:

Here is the detail of parameters:

```
o -- the Object to be compared.

anotherString -- the String to be compared.
```

Return Value :

The value 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string; a value less than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically greater than this string; and a value greater than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically less than this string.

For Example :

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String str1 = "Strings are immutable";
      String str2 = "Strings are immutable";
      String str3 = "Integers are not immutable";

      int result = str1.compareTo( str2 );
      System.out.println(result);

      result = str2.compareTo( str3 );
      System.out.println(result);

      result = str3.compareTo( str1 );
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

Result :
This produces the following result:

```
0
10
-10
```

Answer (score 0):

check the  **`dictionary order`**

```
int compareTo(String str)
```

Here, str is the String being compared with the invoking String. The result of the comparison is returned and is interpreted as shown here:

```
Value                   Meaning 
Less than zero          The invoking string is less than str.
Greater than zero       The invoking string is greater than str. 
Zero                    The two strings are equal.
```